# How to use Excel Logical with Reference based on other cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to right a logical in a cell that returns 1 or 0 depending on if the two values match up or not. Where I am having trouble though is I know the column I want to compare on a different sheet (lets call it A), but the row I need it to depend on a different cell which references a certain cell on a different sheet (=Sheet1A1).

SO basically I want to take the column I know and the row from a reference in a different cell to try to get it to spit out a 1 or a 0.

= SUMIFS(A1,'SHEET 1'!INDEX(D,A1),"(term to match up)")

I just need help walking through it.

Comment: If I follow what you're saying (and I'm not sure I do), you are looking for `INDIRECT("D"&A1)` or `INDIRECT("D"&Sheet1!A1)`

Answer (score 0):

Functions are always a bit tricky since they are translated, but I'll help as best I can.

This is how I interpret your question:

You need to compare a value and return 1 (true) or 0 (false), so you need an `=IF(statement,1,0)` right?
Then you need a cell to compare it to, I reckon `A1` from your example, so `=IF(A1=Value2,1,0)`

Then you need to fetch a row number from a cell, which you can do with `INDIRECT()` and put it together with the known column using `&`.

So if the column of your second value is `A` in the current sheet, and the row is in `Sheet1` and the cell `B2` the code would be `INDIRECT("A"&Sheet1!B2)`

Thus the complete thing would be:

`=IF(A1=INDIRECT("A"&Sheet1!B2),1,0)`